# Extjs proxy just post dirty fields to server, not all filelds

Tags: ajax, extjs, model, proxy

I have a model:

```
Ext.define('CrudTest.model.User', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
idProperty: 'Id',
fields: [
     { name: 'Id', type: 'int' },
    { name: 'Name', type: 'string' },
    { name: 'PhoneNumber', type: 'int' },
    { name: 'Address', type: 'string' },
    { name: 'StateId', type: 'int', reference: 'State' },
],
validators: [
    { type: 'presence', field: 'Name', message: 'define name, please' },
    { type: 'length', field: 'PhoneNumber', max: 8, messsage: 'lower than 8 digit' },

],
proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    api: {
        create: 'home/new',
        read: 'home/users',
        update: 'home/Edit',
        destroy: 'home/Delete'
    },
},
```

});

and a form that load data to form by  **loadRecord()** and my handler code for submit button is:

```
    var form = this.up('form').getForm();
      if (form.isValid()) { 
              form.getRecord().save();
       }
```

it make a post request through my proxy model good. but the body of request just have dirty(edited) fields. why i don't have other fields?

but in request body i have just dirty fields. why? i know updateRecord() uses *getFieldValues([onlyDirty=false])*, how can send all fields values?

I use extjs 5

Comment: the object which is returned by form.getRecord() contains all data or only the dirty fields?

Comment: It contains all data

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally find the problem. [Ext.data.writer.Writer](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.0/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.writer.Writer) has a config property **writeAllFields**

So i change the proxy to this:

```
proxy: {
    writer:{ writeAllFields:true },
    type: 'ajax', //also works with type: 'direct',
    api: {
        create: 'home/new',
        read: 'home/users',
        update: 'home/Edit',
        destroy: 'home/Delete'
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set crtical: true on the Model to any fields you always want written whether changed or not, e.g.

```
{ name: 'title', type: 'string', critical: true }
```